# XCode iOS Distribution Certificates automatically being revoked

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing-certificate

Suddenly I cannot publish a build from XCode to the App Store. My last successful submission was 2 weeks ago and nothing that I can think of has changed. When I validate the publish, I receive the error:

> Missing iOS Distribution signing identity for <%name%>

I look in **XCode/Preferences/*Select profile*/View Details** and all of my signing identities are revoked.

I have deleted my certificates from the developer portal as well as my key chain and recreated in the developer portal and downloaded to key change as instructed here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html

I have also deleted again and let XCode automatically create my certificate. It automatically gets revoked again.

My membership is up-to-date and as far as I'm aware I have abided by the rules! (Apple certainly have told me otherwise). I have never had an app rejected.

Any ideas? I'm running OSX 10.10.2 with XCode 6.4. Literally 2 weeks ago I was working without issues.

Thanks

Comment: I know but such a great community for response time.

Comment: Happy for this to be closed but it could be valuable to others for the next few days so I am going to leave it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **Worldwide Developer Relations Certificate Authority** expired on 14 Feb 2016 so you will need to update it but importantly, you need to remove the expired one by selecting **View/Show Expired Certificates** from Keychain. Ensure that **system** and **certificates** are selected

Comment: Thank you SO much! I have struggled with uploading a build for two hours now, with the strangest errors occurring. Your answer was spot on. I find it really bizarre that the expired certificate is hidden, while there is a newer one that shows in the list, but is being overridden by the expired one.

Comment: This is the way to fix that problem ! Worked for me. Thank you ! It saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is from the *iOS Dev Center* and "**KeyChain Acces**", you need to download the new **"Intermediate certificate"** file by clicking on Create a new certificate.

[image]

1. Click on "Intermediate Certificates" link..
2. Download file
3. Double click

It's solved the problem

Comment: I already figured it out and this is only a part answer. I already did this and the actual problem was that I needed to manually remove the expired one first as explained in my answer.

Comment: I leave here the publication, so that a user need to know how to fix it .. because I spent 15 hours trying to fix it without success, eliminating certificates and other .. And the solution was this ..
If anyone is having the same problem, you can solve.

Comment: I feel you, I spent a similar amount of frustration! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In **Keychain Access > View > Show Expired Certificates** remove all the expired certificates from login. For me, there was also in my **System**, delete from their too.

After deleting all the expired certificates, download the WWDRCA certificate from [here](https://developer.apple.com/certificationauthority/AppleWWDRCA.cer) which expires on 2023.